Failed to register the Ethereum service: ethash is only supported as a historical component of already merged networks
I installed the latest version of Geth for windows on my computer from the official website(https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads), but when I open the terminal and execute the geth command i get the following error Fatal: Failed to register the Ethereum service: ethash is only supported as a historical component of already merged networks. Does anyone know why this happens?
